# Xcode architectures error simulated device for Mac application

Tags: xcode, build

When trying to rebuild an old Mac application Xcode 12.4 show this message:

Please select an available device or choose a simulated device as the destination.
A build only device cannot be used to run this target.

In TARGETS   Architectures is set to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT)
[Standard Architectures (Apple Silicon, Intel)]

This project is for a Mac application not iOS.

Setting  Build Active Architecture Only  to Yes or NO has no effect.

Clean Build Folder  or  removing the folder in DerivatedData do not change anything.

Any help will be greatly appreciate.

Remove the folder in DerivatedData

Comment: What device is picked to run the target?

Comment: "Devices" tab in "Devices and Simulators" window is empty.
I guess this is OK since the project template is a "macOS" "App".

Comment: I don't think it is. If you run the target on the current machine, there should be at least something, e.g., "My Mac."

Comment: "Show as run destination" in "Simulators" tab in "Devices and Simulators" window was check. Uncheck solve the problem. Thank you very much for the advice. I greatly appreciate your help.